# Objective-c class methods and copying return values

Tags: objective-c, return-value, keyword, class-method

I'd like some help understanding the code snippet below.  Specifically I'd like to know why the `copy` keyword is used when `methodB` calls `methodA`.

```
+ (NSString*) methodA {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentsDirectory, 
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}

+ (NSString*) methodB:(NSString*)stringToAppend {

    static NSString *s = nil;
    if(!s) s = [[self methodA] copy];

    return [s stringByAppendingString:stringToAppend];
}
```

Side note:  Apparently class methods can call other class methods using `self` (while instance methods must call class methods like this `[ClassName classMethodName];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MethodB calls copy in case the NSString returned from methodA is actually a NSMutableString.

The copy is just there for security; you can feel safe knowing that nothing is changing the contents of that string while you're using it.

It's a common technique for dealing with objects that might be mutable when you don't want them to be.

Answer (score 0):

What is `paths[0]`? Assuming you meant `[paths objectAtIndex: 0]`, you should at least autorelease it. You can then still copy it in `methodB:`.

The string you return in `methodB:` is already autoreleased, so that is fine.

Comment: No no no no. Don't autorelease it; `[paths objectAtIndex:0]` does not return an owning reference, so you are not responsible for releasing it.